# Proving surjectivity of a function using right inverse function

Tags: abstract-algebra

I define a function $f: (0,1) \longrightarrow R$ as follows.

\begin{align}
f(x) = \,\begin{cases}
\tan(\pi(2x-\frac{1}{2})) &\quad  x \in (0, \frac{1}{2})\\ 
0  &\quad x \in [\frac{1}{2},1)
\end{cases}
\end{align}

When I prove the subjectivity of this function, should I look for the right inverse function or should I just use the definition of surjectivity?

I really can't find the appropriate right inverse function for this case.

Comment: if f is surjective, then f has a right inverse.  Doesn't it? That's what I learned.

Comment: then I still need to find function g that converts x and y from function f, right? so like if f(x) = 2x,   then I set x= 2y and solve for y. Then I get g(x) = 1/2 which I can use when proving surjectivity.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is continuous on $(0,\frac{1}{2})$, and
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = - \infty, \quad \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{x \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}} f(x) = +\infty$$

By the IVT, that means that the image of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $f$ is surjective.